# Setting width/height for the help viewer

Tags: macos, dimensions, help-viewer-1.0

How can I set custom width/height for the help viewer window for my my app?

I searched the [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/user_help_intro/user_assistance_intro.html) for it but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

function resizeWindow()
  {
  window.resizeTo(500,300)
  }